# VBS Excel SaveAs csv FileFormat 62/xlCSVUTF8 doesn´t work

Tags: sql-server, excel, utf-8, vbscript, ansi-sql

I have an VBS Script converting an excel file to csv format called by a SQL server. It contains:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application
Set objBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path, , True)
objBook.Worksheets(i).Activate
objBook.SaveAs file_out_start & i & ".csv", 6, , , True, False, , , , , , True
```

This returns a csv file encoded in **ANSI**.
To further process the file I need the output to be in **UTF-8** encoding.

Following the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat), I tried changing the parameter `6` to `62` representing 'UTF8 CSV'.
With this change the script stops working exiting with following error:

```
line: 36 (line of 'objBook.SaveAs')
error: The SaveAs method of the Workbooks object could not be executed. (translated)
Code: 800A03EC
source: Microsoft Excel
```

Can anyone help why this happens?
If it is not possible to export with UFT-8 encoding directly is there a easy way to convert the files to UFT-8 afterward in the script?

Comment: Why the SQL Server tag? How is this related to SQL Server? In any case, the script you used controls the locally installed Excel instance. Does that instance have such an option? The file is most definitely **NOT** using the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage, it's using the system locale codepage, which is most likely Latin1.

Comment: If the file was ASCII, it would also be UTF8 by definition. UTF8 uses the exact same byte values as ASCII for the first 128 characters. Above that, it uses 2 or more bytes per character. There's no way to tell if a file was created using ASCII or UTF8 unless it contains bytes above 0x7F

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos thank you for your fast reply.
I used the tag, because the main goal is to convert an Excel file to csv in UTF-8 to import data from a remote source to my SQL Server. (I am new to Stack Overflow, sorry if i got something wrong.) 
I know the relationship between ASCII and UTF8, but don`t see the relation to my question: My file is exported as ANSI (another extension of ASCII). Importing the exported file to my sql server creates problems with special characters (ü, ä, ö, ß).
Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem or a better way to realize the project.

Comment: `don't see the relation to my question` on the contrary, that's the most important part. You don't use either ANSI or ASCII. You're probably using Latin1 if your machine uses a US or Western European locale. No matter the codepage, you **can** import any flat file into SQL Server using the `bcp` tool, the `BULK INSERT` command or SSIS. It doesn't need to be in a specific codepage. You can also import directly from Excel with SSIS. You can also use ADO/OLEDB to read data from Excel as if it was a table. Excel is never needed nor used in import scenarios

Comment: VBScript is essentially dead and almost never used. It never really caught as a scripting language and was replaced by Powershell in 2006, which is built on top of .NET and far more powerful. Commands like [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.1) and Import-CSV are built-in, while extra modules like [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) can import and export Excel files

Comment: BUT you don't need to generate a CSV file. You can import directly into SQL Server with eg the [Write-SqlTableData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/write-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) Powershell command. You can load the Excel data with Import-Excel, modify it if needed then send it directly to SQL Server.

Comment: Therer's also the [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/commands/) module that has a *ton* of useful commands, including [Import-DbaCsv](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Import-DbaCsv) which can create a new table based on the CSV data if needed, handle different codepages with the `-Encoding` parameter, multiline-records (they *are* allowed in a CSV), missing likes etc

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I think the issue is Excel can only save a WorkSheet as a csv, not a WorkBook, and therefore needs to use Worksheet.SaveAs instead of Workbook.SaveAs.  My code is below.

Link to Worksheet.SaveAs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.saveas

```
Wscript.Echo "converting .xlsx to UTF8 .csv"
Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
p = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Set book = obj.Workbooks.Open(p & "\filename.xlsx")
obj.Application.Visible = False
Set sheet = book.Worksheets("Sheet1")
book.RefreshAll
obj.DisplayAlerts = False
sheet.SaveAs p & "\filename.csv", 62
book.Close False
Wscript.Echo "closing Excel.Application"
obj.Quit 'Not sure if this does anything but the internet said to use it

Wscript.Echo "End of vbs reached"
```